# Form Submission without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Maybe someone can assist me with this little issue I'm having. I'm trying to submit this form without a page refresh.  But it will skip the post and go directly to the ajax call.  I think I miss understood the preventDefault(). I have searched online but unable to locate what I need for this. Your help would greatly be appreciated or point to another form submission.

HTML below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<title>AJAX | Project</title>
 <link href="project.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>

  </head>
 <body>


<div id="mainCon">

  <h1>Contact Book</h1>
<div id="form_input">
<form id="myform" method="post"    action="addrecord.php">

    <label for="fullname">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname"/><span id="NameError">   </span>
    <br/>
    <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber"><span   id="PhoneError"></span>

    <br />

<input id="buttton" type="submit" onClick="addnumber()" value="Add Phone   Number"/>
    <input type="button" id="show" value="the Results"/>
 </form>


</div>

    <div id="form_output">


    </div>


</div>
 <script src="project.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function addnumber(){

 var Fullname = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
var Phonenumber = document.getElementById("phonenumber").value;



 if(Fullname == ""){
document.getElementById("NameError").innerHTML = "Please Enter a valided Name";
}

if(Phonenumber == ""){
document.getElementById("PhoneError").innerHTML = "Please Enter a valided Name";
}

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#buttton").click(function () {
        $('#myform').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "listrecord.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: "data",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#form_output").html(data);
                },
                error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            }); // AJAX Get Jquery statment
        });
    }); // Click effect     
}); //Begin of Jquery Statement
```

Comment: you don't need click() and submit()

Comment: seems `<input type="submit" action="xxx"/>` will redirect url,

Comment: try data: $('#myform').serialize(),

Comment: you may use a jquery plugin, visit [here](http://mistic100.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/)

Answer (score 47):

Just catch the submit event and prevent that, then do ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
            type: "GET",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#form_output").html(data);
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Adeneo, when i change the url to  $(this).attr('action')  it will post but will re-direct to the "success" post. How can i call a second php file which will show the records?

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean, the success callback is where you get the data ?

Comment: With the form which contains the html.The form <form id="myform" method="post" action="addrecord">. there is a successful echo stating that it was posted.  There is a second php file listreord.php which is the page im looking to call with ajax

Answer (score 19):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#myform');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>

<form id="myform" action="/your_url" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<!-- index.php -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/>
        <input type="submit" name="click" value="button" />
    </form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

         $(function(){
            $("#myForm").submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'submit.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data : $('#myForm').serialize(),
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, desc, err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
<!-- submit.php -->
<?php
$value ="call";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($value);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the Method 'POST' your form is submitting by using the "post" method, and in the AJAX you are using "GET".